# How to prove that B is a subset of A from the axiom of specification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

If we assume the following is true for some formula $\phi$:

$\forall A\exists B \forall x(x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \in A \wedge \phi(x)))$

then B is a subset of A.  That is, $\forall A\exists B\forall x(x \in B \to x \in A)$

I should therefore be able to derive the second formula from the first (?)

This is my attempt using natural deduction, but I'm not sure how to perform existential elimination in order to eliminate the assumption at line 2:

1. $\forall A \exists B \forall x(x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \in A \wedge \phi(x)))$    --- (premise)
2. $\exists B \forall x(x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \in U \wedge \phi(x)))$ --- ($\forall$E)
3. $\forall x(x \in V \leftrightarrow (x \in U \wedge \phi(x)))$ --- (assumption)
4. $x' \in V \leftrightarrow (x' \in U \wedge \phi(x'))$  --- ($\forall$E)
5. $x' \in V \to (x' \in U \wedge \phi(x'))$ --- ($\leftrightarrow$E)
6. $x' \in V$   --- (assumption)
7. $x' \in U \wedge \phi(x')$ --- (MP from 5 and 6)
8. $x' \in U$ --- ($\wedge$E)
9. $x' \in V \to x' \in U$ --- (discharge ass. in 6)
10. $\forall x(x \in V \to x \in U)$ --- ($\forall I$)
11. $\exists B \forall x(x \in B \to x \in U)$ --- ($\exists I$)

???

12. $\forall A\exists B\forall x(x \in B \to x \in A)$ --- ($\forall I$)

Is there any way to get to the final conclusion?  I'm not sure how to discharge the assumption in 3 from here.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Your issue is that you're trying to get from a formula where $B$ is a bound variable to a formula where it is a free variable. Of course you're not going to succeed. What you can however do, is take the forst formula, remove the $\exists B$, and then get to the second one.

Comment: Your initial formula is $\forall A \ \exists B \ldots$ Call them $U$ and $V$ respectively and we get (with your derivation) : $\forall x \ (x \in V \to x \in U)$. Now use $\exists$-I (we can do it) to get: $\exists B \ \forall x \ (x \in B \to x \in U)$ and we can "close" the initial $\exists$-E.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not sure exactly how you close the assumption, I have amended my question above, is this what you mean?  Still not sure what needs to be done between lines 11 and 12.

Comment: I think that now it works... 11) follows from 10) by $\exists$-I and in this way you can close the $\exists$-E started at 3) because the "parameter" $B$ used for the $\exists$-E is no longer free in 11). The 12) follows by $\forall$-I.

Comment: Ah, yes of course!  There are no further steps, I am perpetually getting confused as to how $\exists$E works.  Thanks Mauro...

Comment: @Max Thank you for your contribution, you're right, I could just alternatively take the $\exists$B off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: $\forall A\exists B\forall x(x \in B \to x \in A)$ is saying: every set $A$ has a subset $B$.  Well, yes, for any set $A$ as you can simply pick $B = \emptyset$.

OK, so clearly this is not what you want to get at!

You want to say that 'the set $B$ that consists of all elements of $A$ that have property $\phi$ is a subset of $A$'. Now, to symbolize that, we can do:

$\forall A \exists B (\forall x (x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \in A \wedge \phi(x))) \land \forall x (x \in B \rightarrow x \in A))$

But, I think a little nicer would be to prove:

$\forall A \forall B (\forall x (x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \in A \wedge \phi(x))) \rightarrow \forall x (x \in B \rightarrow x \in A))$

(which does not depend on the actual existence of $B$). Here is a proof:

[image]

and then when you do guarantee the existence of $B$ from the axiom of specification, you can use this result to immediately infer that $B$ is a subset of $A$ once you have introduced this $B$:

[image]

Indeed, we can extend this proof to prove the earlier suggested statement:

$\forall A \exists B (\forall x (x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \in A \wedge \phi(x))) \land \forall x (x \in B \rightarrow x \in A))$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed, I just didn't know how exactly to formulate the proof.

Comment: @esotechnica Cool, glad I could help! :)

Comment: I am assuming that this is the simplest way of deriving the final result from the axiom of specification.  It seems so cumbersome to get to a truth that is glaringly obvious!  I wouldn't have the mathematical insight to ever be able to see this proof's pathway, I wish I could develop this.  Hopefully practice is all I need...

Comment: @esotechnica Yeah, formal proofs can be a bit funny that way, especially because not all formal proof systems have the same rules (so indeed, if you have to produce a formal proof in some specific system, the formal proof above may not comply to its specific inference rules ... the formal proof above was produced by using 'Fitch'). It usually takes a little getting used to, but you're right, the key is just to practice! :)